# Can one surah be used in FARD prayers?

Tags: salat, fard

When praying fard, is it allowed for one long surah be used for both of the raka'at?

e.g. Praying ayahs 1-15 of surah mulk for the first raka'at and then continuing for ayahs 16-30 of surah mulk

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Imams often and regularly break up surat similarly when reciting in tarawih.

Generally, only al-Fatihah is considered strictly necessary when reciting fard salat; beyond that you may recite from the Qur'an however is easy for you.

To my knowledge, the general ruling for any recitation after al-Fatihah is that it should be at least three *ayat*, but there's no requirement that this recitation needs make up a complete surah.